# JNDI Issues: Jboss 4.2.2 Spring 2.5 and hibernate ejb

Tags: java, jboss, datasource

I have a strange problem, that is causing me some grief.  If the following jar is in my classpath:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>org.hibernate.ejb</artifactId>
<version>3.3.2.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

My JNDI lookup for my datasource returns null.  Here is the basic code I am using to do the lookup:

```
InitialDirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
DataSource dataSource = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:dataContent");
```

Otherwise, the DataSource returns fine from the context.  Unfortunately, I need the jar in order to avoid ClassCastExceptions within Jboss 4.2.2.

Any help is appreciated.

```
<datasources>
<local-tx-datasource>
<jndi-name>dataContent</jndi-name>
<connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@server.net:1521:XXX</connection-url>
<min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
<max-pool-size>5</max-pool-size>
<user-name>dbuser</user-name>
<valid-connection-checker-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.OracleValidConnectionChecker</valid-connection-checker-class-name>
<exception-sorter-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.OracleExceptionSorter</exception-sorter-class-name>
<password>dbpasswd</password>
<driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
</local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

Comment: What do you mean it returns null but otherwise returns fine? And what does the jar have to do with the question?

Comment: Returning fine means non-null datasource.  I am not sure what the jar has to do with it, but I wonder if it is a hibernate 3 vs jboss 4.2.2 issue.  I tried upgrading the hibernate jars on the server, but it did not help.

Comment: Can you post the datasource definition in the -ds.xml file?

Comment: It sounds odd that you should need to bundle hibernate in JBoss in order to avoid a ClassCastExceptions. Can you describe the error you get.

Answer (score 0):

As I remeber JBoss 4.2 is EJB3/JPA compatable and thus the hibernate persistence implementation should only be used for compilation. The following maven dependency should accomplish this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.hibernate.ejb</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

If you are only using the JPA part you might further trim down by only depending on the **javax.persistence** api.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like including that dependency is bringing in transitively some other jars too. Make sure your application does *not* package JBoss specific jar files. In this case, I think it might be the presence of jboss-common-core.jar in your application which might be resulting in this issue. Remove that jar (and any other JBoss specific jar files) - you can add a  in the maven dependency.

Comment: Jaikiran, it came out as "you can add a in the maven dependency"; did you mean "you can add a 'provided' in the maven dependency", as another answer shows?